# Two if(isset($_POST) arrays in one update query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to bring an id from a hidden form on a previous page and using it as a variable as part of an update query.

The path to this point is....: 
Log in to admin area (using a different table)... 
Search 'businesses' database for entry...
Entry displays with an update button, the update button has a hidden ID... value that gets posted to this page through "submit"...

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["submituname"]))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["uname"];
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE businesses SET username='$name' WHERE id='$id'");

    if($query)
    {
        $msguname = "<p>Your username has now been updated.</p>";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: if($query) is not good check.. instead check mysqli_affected_rows  == 1

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is. Also you are mixing the quotes, in sql commands the single quote should be used for string parameters not the double quotes.

Comment: Problem in single quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `isset()` on both variables to check them both.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST["submituname"]))
```

You're sql query is current open to injection attack, make sure you use PDO or mysqli_real_escape_string().

Comment: Thanks Tristan. Purely testing on a local server at the moment will be adding mysqli_real_escape_string(). Thanks for the help and heads up though.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes..

1. Is that all functions must be inside your IF.. (so they are triggered only when its a post request and etc.
2. You must set isset to both post params which you are checking
3. What will you do if id is not set ? In that case I am giving a small easy trick by using filter_input which return NULL on not set param (another thing is escaping but I will leave you small task to learn how to escape vars..)
4. Last thing is your if($query) .. this is wrong check if you have any success.

Here is a working copy

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && ($_POST["submituname"])) {
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id');
    $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE businesses SET username='{$name}' WHERE id={$id}");
    if(mysqli_affected_rows($db) === 1){
        $msguname = "<p>Your username has now been updated.</p>";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Svetilo great explanation. I had no luck unfortunately. I think I may have been a little vague in what I was trying to achieve.

It is to to update a table from an admin area. The path to this point is:

Log in to admin area (using a different table)
Search 'businesses' database for entry
Entry displays with an update button, the update button has a hidden ID value that gets posted to this page.

Does that help at all?